Prove the Erdős-Sós Conjecture for paths $P_{k+1}$
The conjecture says:
If $G$ is a graph, and $e(G) > \frac{n}{2} (k-1)$, then $G$ contains every tree of size $k$.
I don't even know how this can be proven in the first place. If $G = P_{k+1}$, then $e(G) = k$ and $n = k+1$. But it's not true, that
$$k > \frac{(k+1)(k-1)}{2}$$

What you've checked is that $P_{k+1}$ does not satisfy the hypothesis of the conjecture. Which is good, because $P_{k+1}$ does not contain every tree of size $k$. I think you've misunderstood the question: to prove the conjecture for paths means that you're supposed to substitute $P_{k+1}$ for "tree of size $k$", not for $G$. So you must prove that if $G$ is an $n$-vertex graph, and $e(G) > \frac n2(k-1)$, then $G$ contains $P_{k+1}$.
